# jQuery - wait for class to be applied before it is removed

Tags: jquery, addclass, race-condition

I am applying a class to a google map, and immediately afterwards running a function. Once the function is complete, the class is then removed.

On certain mobile browsers, I am sometimes seeing the class not being removed, im guessing as the class being added is still completing.

Is there a way I can guarantee that the class has been applied before I start my function? I could add a timer, and this seems to work, but is there a better way?

My code looks something like:

```
$('#map').addClass('fade-map');

function doStuff() {
       ...
    }

$('#map').removeClass('fade-map');
```

Comment: If you don't call your function in the code it won't be executed

Comment: why not just put the removeClass call at the end of the doStuff function?

Comment: There's no really "when function ends". Perhaps your function has some async work in it and ends rather quickly. What it has? You need to call the .removeClass() when the function really ends. Its too fast? then apply a setTimeout after function call, then remove the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (this pattern)

```
var map = $('#map');
$.when(map.addClass("fade-map").data("on", true))
.done(function(_map) {
    function  doStuff() {
        // do stuff , 
        // e.g. , 
        // _map.text(_map.data("on")).animate({fontSize:"24px"}, 5000, "linear");
        _map.data("on", false);
    };
    // if _`map` (`$("#map")`) has class `fade-map` , do sutff
    if (_map.is(".fade-map") && _map.data("on") === true) {
      doStuff();
    }
})
.always(function(_map) {
     if (_map.is(".fade-map") && _map.data("on") === false) {
       // remove class , do stuff
      _map.removeClass("fade-map").append("\n" + _map.data("on"));
      console.log(_map.is(".fade-map"));
    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/h27o58ft/

See [jQuery .is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript functions in a block will run without breaks in the order of the control flow unless you introduce timeouts or create event listeners.

It looks like your doStuff may include some animation functions. A parameter of most jQuery animation functions is a callback that runs once the animation loop is complete.

See the relevant [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) page.

hopefully this helps:

```
$('#map').addClass('fade-map');

// --- doStuff
// .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
$('#map').animate(
    {opacity:0},
    function(){
        $('#map').removeClass('fade-map');
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

JS is executed in a sequential manner, meaning the class will always be applied first then your function will execute, then the class will be removed. That said:

```
 $('#map').addClass('fade-map');

    var t = setInterval(function(){
      if($('#map').hasClass('fade-map')){
        /*execute your other function here - THIS BETTER NOT HAVE TIMEOUTS/INTERVALS OF
 IT's OWN or you'll see the same behavior. As someone below said in case you do have 
animations or stuff like that, you should remove class in a callback function of the animation*/
        $('#map').removeClass('fade-map');
        clearInterval(t);
      }
    },100);
```

This is a nasty way of doing it though.

Example of callback:

```
$('#map').addClass('fade-map').animate({'property1':'valueX'},function(){$(this).removeClass('fade-map')});
```